# Find the expression for the path length on the surface of the cylinder with constant

Tags: dynamical-systems, euler-lagrange-equation

Hi just working on some past exam questions for an upcoming quiz for a class in Lagrangian dynamics, and I am a bit stuck on this question (which seems quite different from what we have done in class):

> (i) Let $ds$ be the small distance between neighbouring points. Show
>   that in cylindrical coordinates $ds^2=dr^2+r^2dθ^2+dz^2$
>
> (ii) Find the expression for the path length on the surface of the
>   cylinder with constant $r=a$
>
> $$ I= \int_{z_0}^{z_1} \frac{ds}{dz}dz $$
>
> (iii) Find the function $θ(z)$ that describes the path of least length
>   between the points $(a,0,0)$ and $(a,π,H)$

I'm stuck on parts (ii) and (iii).

For (ii) I use the result to obtain:

$$\frac{ds}{dz} = \sqrt{r^2(\frac{d\theta}{dz})^2 + (\frac{dr}{dz})^2 + 1}$$ but then I'm not too sure how to integrate this?

I'm also assuming the answer to his question leads to (iii).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If the radius is fixed, then all the of the terms involving $ dr $ will vanish. So your result for (ii) should look like $$ I = \int_{z_0}^{z_1} \sqrt{ a^2 \left( \frac{d\theta}{dz}\right)^2  + 1} \; dz $$ You should not try to integrate this, but instead find the Euler-Lagrange equations in the usual way, and then try to solve them.

If you let $ x = a \theta $, then it is identical to finding the shortest line connecting two points on the plane. This is of course because the cylinder is flat - you can slice it along the length and spread it out into a rectangle, and then find the shortest length there.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. Taking the integrand, I took the first integral and solved for $\theta$, getting $\theta = \sqrt{a^2-\frac{a^4}{c^2}}z+c_1$ - does this seem correct? I'm still a bit confused on the last part, my expression does not contain $x$?..

Comment: I didn't do the calculation, but that seems right - just a confusing way of writing $ \theta = c_1 z + c_2 $, which are indeed the geodesics. Now just fit the initial and final conditions. Don't worry about the last part of my answer, I just meant to say that the reason you get straight lines for geodesics is because the cylinder is flat.

Comment: Right. So part (iii) is essentially just solving for the constants. thanks!